# Suppress uninitailized perl warning

Tags: perl

Is there a way I can suppress uninitialized Perl variable warning for only few libraries out of all the libraries used in a Perl file?

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: File::Path and Win32

Comment: If either of those modules are raising *uninitialised* warnings then there is a bug in your code that calls them. You don't need to (and shouldn't) disable the warning

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any reason this would be a good idea, surely use of an uninitialised variable is a bug which ever angle you look at it from?

However, you can turn the warnings off with:

```
no warnings 'uninitialized';
```

And on again with:

```
use warnings 'uninitialized';
```

You can disable the warnings for a single statement if you surround it with these two statements.

Comment: Use of undefined variables may or may not be a bug, depending on what you're doing and how you're doing it. That's why "Use of uninitialized value" is a suppressible warning rather than a fatal error.

Comment: @DaveSherohman I can't disagree with you, it's just that in 20 years I can't think of a case where I had this and considered it not a bug. If I did I'd probably want to fix it anyway, on the basis that it is a bug that it emits the warning during compile :)

Comment: @Michael  
 
    no warnings 'uninitialized';     use Win32; use warnings 'uninitialized';     use File::Path;   Will the above suppress uninitialized warnings from Win32 and display the ones from File::Path?

Comment: It doesn't follow use, sorry. The modules are compiled separately. I just tried "require MOD" instead of "use MOD" to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't.

Comment: use common::sense;

Answer (score 1):

You probably used `-w`, which enables warnings throughout the interpreter (though it can be overridden using `local $^W = 0;` or `no warnings;`).

It's not a bad thing to use `-w`. All modules should tolerate this or defend against it (using `no warnings;`). But some aren't "warnings-safe".

It's more conventional to place `use warnings;` in each of your scripts and modules. This is method of enabling warnings is less intrusive since it won't affect other third-party modules used by your script and modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to modify the offending module(s), you can add `no warnings 'uninitialized';` to the module itself, outside of any `sub` declarations, and it will disable that category of warnings for all code in the module, as demonstrated with these two bits of code:

In `warntest`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use lib '.';

use UndefMod;

my $x;
say "Main before: $x";

UndefMod::test_mod;
say "Main after: $x";
```

In `UndefMod.pm` (in the same directory):

```
package UndefMod;

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

no warnings 'uninitialized';

sub test_mod {
  my $x;
  say "Module: $x";
}

1;
```

When run, this produces "Use of uninitialized value" warnings for both `say`s in `warntest`, but no warning for the `say` in `UndefMod`, thus showing that either file's `warnings` setting has no effect on the other.

Of course, you may not be able to modify the module source, in which case you may be out of luck.  Perl's scoping rules don't generally allow you to modify the warnings/no warnings state of a scope from outside that scope.  (I say "may" and "generally" because there may be some black magic to hack around that, probably at least related to the magic behind PadWalker, but such things are beyond my ken.)